# Yiga Clan guards pestering me. What to do?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The Yiga Clan were always a little pain. They would stop you, decide to fight you, and then you could just open a can of whoopass on them and continue your way.

But after clearing the hideout, now there's the guards that spawn every once in a while. And they are not like their old counter parts. They WILL one shot you.

Is there a way to stop/prevent them from spawning? A side quest to do that will make their random attacks stop? It's pretty annoying that out of nowhere I have to run away ASAP.

Comment: I've found tagging them with an ice arrow and pulling your biggest weapon out helps.

Comment: If the Yiga are one-shotting you after you cleared their hideout, you should focus on getting more hearts and/or upgrading your armor.  Yiga blademasters are coded to one-shot kill in the hideout, but after that, they deal damage normally.  Once you get decent armor, they're more of an annoyance that anything.

Comment: Yeah Gerudo was my 2nd dungeon so I was still pretty squishy. Later on they are a lot less of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prevent this from happening. Hey, at least they drop some nice and powerful items. You can, however, run away and not look back.

Comment: In this game the run away technic fastly becomes the most optimal option against minions.